# Replace spaces by underscores in files: Error in my bash script

Tags: bash, variable

I don't understand the error in my bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
newFile=""
for file in *
do
    newFile={$file/ /_}     # so as to replace spaces with underscores
    mv {$file} {$newFile}
done
```

It complains that `newFile` is not a command in the line `newFile={$file/ /_}`

I guess I'm doing things wrong, but I keep stumbling on that point.

Comment: why not use a simple `sed -i s/ /_/g   *`

Comment: You need to place the `$` in front of the `{` like `${file}` and `${file/ /_}`

Comment: @AmitKumar; The OP wants to rename the files, not replacing all the spaces with _ *within* the files.

Comment: And besides quoting the variable use also `${file// /_}` (a double slash after file) to have all the spaces replaced with an underscore instead of only the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the position of the $ and add a last `/` to the sub to perform it for all spaces. You also need to quote the variables as it will see the space in the filename as a delimiter between the arguments for mv.

```
#!/bin/bash
newFile=""
for file in *
do
    newFile=${file// /_}     # so as to replace spaces with underscores
    mv "{$file}" "{$newFile}"
done
```

Although as stated in the other answer, half of this script is redundant.

```
newFile=""
```

Is not needed at all as the variable can be first referenced in the assignment later on.

```
 newFile=${file// /_}
```

Although the assignment itself is also not needed as the parameter substituion does not alter the original.

So it can be rewritten as

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *
do
    mv "${file}" "${file// /_}" 
done
```

Comment: @don_crissti I hadn't finished editting it sorry.

Comment: @don_crissti also do you not get a 5 min grace period on this site ?

Comment: @don_crissti Dunno what its called i just heard someone say that once, on stackoverflow you have 5 mins to edit the answer without it coming up as edited.

Comment: You have maybe a couple of minutes not more...

Comment: @don_crissti ah right, okay :)

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question based on the comments on your question:

1. You need to put the dollar charachter `$` before the curly brace
   character `{`.
2. Besides that it is a good practice to quote (`""`) your variables.
3. And finally, to have all the spaces replaced by an underscore you
   need to use two slashes (`//`) to be 'greedy' on the replacement.

So a sample script will look like:

```
#!/bin/bash

for myfile in *
do
    mv "${myfile}" "${myfile// /_}"
done
```

**Note:** There is no need to have an additional variable to hold the new name